# How to run javascript in multiple tabs using javascript executor

Tags: javascript, java

I am using javascript executor in java to make execute script in selenium java.

My question is how to make run javascript executor in more than one tabs only using javascript.

I have solution in java in that I may use

```
driver.switchto(windowhandles).
```

But I need the output based on only javascript

```
driver.get(URL1 );
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            JavascriptExecutor js1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                js.executeScript("window.document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {" 
                        +"console.log('Clicked');" 
                        +"console.log('');"                         
                        +"window.open('http://www.google.com', 'New Window', 'width=screen.width,height=screen.height');"
                        +"e.stopImmediatePropagation();"
                        + "})" 
                        );
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                List<String> browserWindow = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
                driver.switchTo().window(browserWindow .get(1));
                if(browserWindow.get(1) != null)    
                {
                    js1.executeScript(""
                            +"window.document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {" 
                            +"console.log('Clicked on new Window');" 
                            +"console.log('');" 
                            + "})" 
                            );
                }
            }           
     catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: i post my code.

Comment: I just noticed that the javascript executor executes the script in all tabs. I opened two tabs and performed the document.title script and got the titles of both tabs.